# How do I keep checked radio button on the next page with php?

Tags: javascript, php, html

[pict of My Project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RdgxM.png)

I have this file, i want when i choose the answer,And , then the value of radio button not change when i click back. please help me..

```
while( $row = mysqli_fetch_array($sql)){
    ?>
      <tr>
        <td><?php echo $no;?></td>
        <td><?php echo  $row['soal']; ?></td>
        <td><input type="radio" name="jawabana" value="<?php echo  $row['a']; ?>" <?php if(isset($_POST['jawabana']) && ($_POST['jawabana'] == $row['a'])) echo 'checked="checked" ';?>><?php echo  $row['a']; ?></td>
        <td><input type="radio" name="jawabanb" value="<?php echo  $row['b']; ?>" <?php if(isset($_POST['jawabanb']) && ($_POST['jawabanb'] == $row['b'])) echo 'checked="checked" ';?>><?php echo  $row['b']; ?></td>
        <td><input type="radio" name="jawabanc" value="<?php echo  $row['c']; ?>" <?php if(isset($_POST['jawabanc']) && ($_POST['jawabanc'] == $row['c'])) echo 'checked="checked" ';?>><?php echo  $row['c']; ?></td>
        <td><input type="radio" name="jawaband" value="<?php echo  $row['d']; ?>" <?php if(isset($_POST['jawaband']) && ($_POST['jawaband'] == $row['d'])) echo 'checked="checked" ';?>><?php echo  $row['d']; ?></td>
      </tr>
    <?php
  $no++;
  }
```

full script here https://pastebin.com/RJ2XxJrn

Thanks!

Comment: You need to somehow now which one should be checked, when you do. It's HTML. <input checked="checked" />

Comment: i have do it, but it can't solve my problem

Comment: for radio button to work, you need to give all the radio input the same name, try giving them all the same name.

Comment: i do give all the same name, but it's not working :(

Comment: please try with replacing all the `"jawabana/b/c/d"` with `"jawaban-$no"`, in your above code.

Comment: okay, i'll try it

Comment: not working :( @RaghavGarg

Comment: can you please explain more about "the behaviour you want" vs "the behaviour you are getting."

Comment: i want to make a quiz online, show 5 question/page, and 4answer( multiple choice) /question,
what i get, the radio button can't save the answer when i click next page, and when i click previous page, the answer gone @RaghavGarg

Comment: Radio buttons, forms, web pages, don't just automatically "remember" the state of the form controls — _you_ have to code something to save them. You can `POST` them back to your server, or use cookies to retain the values (choices), or write the values to `localStorage` etc. The other thing Ragahav Garg is trying to tell you is: a set of radio buttons all have to have the same name; yours are named jawabana, jawabanb, etc, which are _not_ the same; but then each _group_ of radio buttons must have a different name. `jawaban-$no` will make 4 btns in group 1 "jawaban-1" and in group 2 "jawaban-2"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once a radio button is checked it cannot be be unchecked by clicking it again, u must use checkbox instead of radio, and then style it to look as a radio button, here is the code which use jquery to make check boxes act as both check box and radio

```js
$('input[name="test_input"]').click(function(){
  var valueNow = $('input[name="test_input"]').prop('checked');
  $('input[name="test_input"]').not(this).prop('checked',false);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" value="value1" name="test_input">
<input type="checkbox" value="value2" name="test_input">
<input type="checkbox" value="value3" name="test_input">
<input type="checkbox" value="value4" name="test_input">
```

Comment: if i use checkbox, user can check more then 1 answer, any other solution?

Comment: to overcome this you can use some jquery which makes checkbox act as a radio button, i will work it out and edit my answer, wait

Comment: hmm okay, i'll try it too

Answer (score 0):

Use **autocomplete** feature of HTML, like below :

```
<form .... autocomplete="on">
   <input type="radio" name="jawabanb" value="1">
   <input type="radio" name="jawabanb" value="2">
   <input type="radio" name="jawabanb" value="3">
</form>
```

Comment: please explain your answer. Just posting the code is not the solution.

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is the variable settings, Save the answers in the Session variable, and check it there in the echo statements, so when you hit back, the post variable is not lost.

Comment: can you give me an example?